# How can i use DomainUpDown as spinner?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to control domainUpDown as spinner to control value from 0 to 800 so that if i hit its upper arrow it adds 1 into current value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant says, the NumericUpDown is your best choice. Set the minimum value to 0, which it should be already as the default, and the maximum to 800. You can access the number by using the "value" property on the NumericUpDown object.